# no print output after obtaining input from msvcrt.getch() on same line

Tags: python, printing, msvcrt

**Goals**:

- Get single char input from user from same line, without having to press `ENTER`,
- Print after user selects an option.

**Code**:

```
import msvcrt

print("Overwrite? (y/n): ", end="", flush=True)
res = msvcrt.getch()

if res.upper() == 'Y':
    print("The file has been overwritten.")
```

Currently, the print statement below does not get printed after I input `y` into the program.

```
print("The file has been overwritten.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, `msvcrt.getch()` will return a `bytes` type instead of a `str`, so you have to decode the input to `utf-8` before trying to check its value:

```
import msvcrt

print("Overwrite? (y/n): ", end="", flush=True)
res = msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

if res.upper() == 'Y':
    print("The file has been overwritten.")
```